# How to stop a Spring Batch job no matter what step it's on

Tags: spring-batch

I know there's a common pattern to stop a job when certain exceptions are thrown. But we allow our users to stop any job at any time.

I have a number of microservices, each running a different batch job. In the front, have a controller method that looks up all running jobs, gets the execution Id, and then uses `JobOperator` to issue a stop command. But execution appears to continue.

```
jobOperator.stop(Long.parseLong(jobExecId));
```

All of the examples I've seen have issued just this command and updated the `JobRepository`, which I do.

```
    jobExecution.setEndTime(new Date());
    jobExecution.setStatus(BatchStatus.ABANDONED);
    jobExecution.setExitStatus(ExitStatus.STOPPED);
    jobRepository.update(jobExecution);
```

Is there something more I should be doing?

Comment: There is no way to force immediate shutdown, especially when the control is in user's code. `execution appears to continue`: does it continue until completion or does the job stop but not immediately? The `StepInterruptionPolicy` (which defaults to `ThreadStepInterruptionPolicy` as mentioned by Luca) is checked at chunk boundaries, so there is no reason the job does not stop when the control gets back to the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose calling `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` should be the right way to proceed.
SB will intercept signal in `ThreadStepInterruptionPolicy` and stops the job.